# Django keeps returning local variable 'product' referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, django, view, model

I stored a list of products in my django models with multiple images attached to each product as a foreignkey. I am trying to retrieve all the products and their respective images in my django views so that I can print them on the screen. However no matter what I do I keep getting the local variable 'product' reference before assignment error.

```
Models.py:
   class product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('', max_length=100,  db_index=True)
    price = models.CharField('', max_length=100,  db_index=True)
    description = models.CharField('', max_length=100,  db_index=True)

   class productimage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_images = models.FileField(blank=True)


views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render
from selling.models import product
from selling.models import productimage
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.template import loader

template = loader.get_template("selling/shop.html")
    if product.objects.exists():
        products = product.objects.all()
        for product in products:
            productimages = product.productimage_set.all()
            for productimage in productimages:
                imageurl = productimage.product_image.url
            context = {
                    "products" : products,
                    "productimages" : productsimages,
                }
```

Comment: It's a very strong convention in Django for model classes to begin with uppercase letters. It's possible that if you had followed that here you would have noticed your error earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to import product in view. So update your code like this:

```
from .models import product   # use camel case when writing class name
```

Also you implementation is bit complicated in views(looping over product and product images). You can move most of them to template like this:

```
template = loader.get_template("selling/shop.html")
products = product.objects.all()
if products.exists():
    context = {
            "products" : products,
    }
```

Template:

```
{% for product in products %}
     {% for product_image in product.productimage_set.all %}
         <img src="{{product_image.product_image.url}}">
     {% enfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I imported the product at the top of the views.
I've added it to the views to reflect that

Comment: I think Python is getting confused because it sees that you have a local variable `product` (the variable inside the `for` loop, which is assigned to each element of `products` in turn) - and therefore thinks that `if product.objects.exists()` is referencing it (before it's been assigned, hence the error). Try just using a different name for the loop variable (I agree that `product` is the most natural one though - so as I said in a comment earlier, the best fix is to make your model name `Product` instead).

Answer (score 2):

You could import product with a different name (or) change the variable name. 
like 
`from selling.models import product as product_model`
So in rest of the code you can use `product_model`. That should clear all confusion and hence you should not have any issues.